# Adding Aruba switch to monitoring tool via SNMP protocol

Tags: networking, monitoring, snmp, aruba, observium

I am trying to add few aruba switches to a monitoring platform `observium` but failing to do so.
the coumminity string and the trap address are perfectly fine but it doesnot seem to work. It would be great if anyone could help.

1. I have tried troubleshooting with snmpwalk cli tool and the switch
   is not sending in data.
2. It seems that the switch is enabled with VRF, please let me know if the
   process is different for VRF enabled switches.

Comment: I will suggest you use a tool like Wireshark to actually see into the packets. You currently have no proof that the switch sent out SNMP TRAP packets so no one here can tell how to help.

Comment: Actually there was some problem with the switch configuration with gui, the switch was reconfigured from cli and it started working, thanks.